# How to access a value within a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON object notation:

```
[{"getCname('mail.fred.com.au')":[{"cname":"www.fred.com.au"}]}]
```

and am unsure how to only access the "`cname`" value alone in JavaScript, i.e. I just require:

```
"www.fred.com.au"
```

I have tried `res[0].cname` but this didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have

```
let object = [{"getCname('mail.fred.com.au')":[{"cname":"www.fred.com.au"}]}];
```

then you can get that URL value via

```
let url = object[0]["getCname('mail.fred.com.au')"][0].cname;
```

The outer object is an array, and the value of the property with the long strange name is also an array, hence the `[0]` in two places.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit cludgy but if you don't know the 'getCname' key you can do:

```
let res = [{"getCname('mail.fred.com.au')":[{"cname":"www.fred.com.au"}]}];
let key = Object.keys(res[0])[0];

let cname = res[0][key][0].cname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these

```
var res = [{"getCname('mail.fred.com.au')":[{"cname":"www.fred.com.au"}]}];

res[0] ;// returns Object  {"getCname('mail.fred.com.au')":[{"cname":"www.fred.com.au"}]};

res[0]["getCname('mail.fred.com.au')"] ;//returns Array [{"cname":"www.fred.com.au"}];

res[0]["getCname('mail.fred.com.au')"][0].cname ;//returns "www.fred.com.au"
```